# Threadsafe Stack

Tags: java, stack, locking

Here is a class which I have written to create a simple [Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) data structure which can be shared across multiple threads.

It's a simple LIFO which has 2 operations: one to push onto the top of the stack and the other one to pop from the top of the stack.

Please help me to find any issues with it.

```
package com.thread.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class ThreadSafeStack<T> {

    private List<T> list;
    private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock;

    public ThreadSafeStack() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<T>();
        lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    }

    public T pop() {
        try {
            lock.writeLock().lock();
            if(!list.isEmpty()) {
                return list.remove(list.size()-1);
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.println("In finally");
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean push(T t) {
        try {
            lock.writeLock().lock();
            return list.add(t);

        }
        finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with thread safety in Java, but from a little research, should your data structure implementation make use of the `synchronized` keyword? I may be wrong if that is handled by `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock`. However, I do not see anything on [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html), it only mentions it is reentrant, not thread-safe.

Comment: What's wrong with a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`?

Comment: @mtj - I am trying to learn concurrency, thread safety and locking. So trying to use bare bones JDK.

Comment: @esote my understanding is the `synchronized` pretty much provides shorthand for what the OP has done. In this instance, since they are not exploiting multi-read/one-write features of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, a `synchronise` based solution might be preferable from a 'it's harder to get wrong' point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine, some minor improvements below...

- make the private members final
- If only using the write locking of ReentrantReadWriteLock just use a ReentrantLock
- use the [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface for the lock `private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock()`
- in pop() throw an exception rather than returning null if the stack is empty
- Replace the system.out w/ a Logger
- Consider adding some javadocs to help the users of your implementation

Comment: Why throw an exception instead of returning null? That makes no sense.

Comment: Then it is clear that the stack was empty so pop() was invalid, similar to [java.util.Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop--). What if we do push(null), then pop(), was it empty or are we returning items that were added

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally review Java, but your code looks like it should work. You might consider using the `synchronised` language feature instead in this instance, as you are not gaining anything from manually using `ReentrantReadWriteLock` (e.g. you don't have anything which uses a `Read` lock (e.g. `tryPeek`)).

---

I appreciate that you want to use a minimal subset of the `JDK`, but I'd still advocate a [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) as the backing data-structure, since it (unsurprisingly) better represents the data, and in doing so reduces the opportunity for errors (e.g. ensuring you remove the topmost element, etc).

---

The `return null` in `pop` is not great, as your data-structure could just as well hold a `null`; it should either `throw` when you try to remove an element that doesn't exist, or you should provide some wrapper type which indicates whether a value was retrieved. At a minimum, the fact that the method returns `null` when the queue is empty should be clearly documented.

If the `return null` is to remain, I'd move it (or indeed a `throw` which replaces it) into an `else` clause within the `try...catch`, so that it is closer to the logic which determines it. Others might suggest inverting the `if`, so that you `throw`/`return null` on `list.isEmpty()`, and perform the meaningful operation otherwise.

---

Declaring `"In finally"` to the console might be useful for debugging, but as a consumer, this would infuriate me. Your class should provide a meaningful interface, and it shouldn't have any such unnecessary external influence.

---

You might consider making `list` and `lock` `final`, which will ensure they are assigned within the constructor, and prevent their being overwritten by accident. The type isn't disposable, so there is no need to clear the references at any point.

---

Be consistent in your styling: you use `this.list`, and then on the next line just `lock`. You've also a random empty line half way through `push`, with the rest of your code devoid of any spacing.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve but one of the below implementations should suit your requirements:

- [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) {since 1.7}
- [BlockingDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) {since 1.6}

(If you're just trying to reinvent the wheel for educational purposes, I will recommend reading the source code of above mentioned java classes.)